# How to adjust CSS responsiveness of Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just installed a Bootstrap theme on my Wordpress page and try to adjust the CSS to a certain degree.

One of my problems is related to the carousel. At the moment, when I resize my website (or look at it on a mobile device),...

1. The carousel maintains a really large height (resulting in me only seeing a very small part as it reduces to a square on the mobile screen)
2. The caption disappears

How can I adjust these two aspects. I would like the height to decrease at smaller screen sizes, so the original dimensions can be maintained better. Also, I would like to keep the caption (probably at a smaller font size though).

I looked through various websites, found some stackoverflow questions and [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-control-the-width-an-height-of-my-carousel) website, but couldn't solve my problems.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries in your CSS to change the height of the carousel and the font size at different breakpoints.
Or, if you're using Bootstrap, have you tried adding in the breakpoints to the html classes?

Comment: Well I've tried the former, but given that the boostrap css is 9,000 rows long, I'm not sure where to look. What happens to the caption is set up in the .caption class, but I can only find that once. I was expecting a display: none in case the screen size changes, but can't find it. Other classes used for the caption part are d-none and d-md-flex, but they don't differ in the large version, so I'm not sure whether they drive what I want to change.

Comment: you need to investigate little on media queries of bootstrap @Berbatov

Comment: I wonder if this article might help? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-to-use-bootstrap-for-your-wordpress-theme-and-when-not-to--cms-23561